# Is there a shorter way to use try / catch exceptions?

Tags: php

Been inside `nodejs` for a while and just came back to PHP. It seemed much more simpler to entertain  `try/catch` blocks in `Javascript` :

```
try{
throw('Hello!');
}catch(e){
console.log(e);
}
```

..Which is only ***70*** characters long.

And now in PHP:

```
try{
throw new Exception('Hello!');
}catch(Exception $e){
var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

..Which is over ***108*** characters long.
That is about **54%** more characters that need to be used.

Is there a way to shorten this block up so it's more like `Javascript's` `try/catch` blocks?  Does an extension exist perhaps, or maybe a different way but has the same function?

Comment: As PHP supports different types of exceptions (and you need to indicate which type you're throwing), and you might want to handle different exception types differently when you catch them, the answer is "No".... and is it really critical to save 38 characters in a PHP script?

Comment: Simply put, PHP !== Javascript

Comment: Not writing this question gave you 4 free try catch blocks. :)

Comment: Good point Mark, just was curious because in the future I will be writing a lot of Exceptions. I guess I need to make the mental switch when switching between node and php and abide by such rules and accept them.

Comment: You could use an IDE with auto-complete, which will save you some key-strokes.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that in PHP you can have different catch blocks to handle different types of errors, like so:

```
        try
        {
            // Do something here
        }
        catch(\PauseException $exception)
        {
        }
        catch(\GotoException $exception)
        {
        }
        catch(\FatalException $exception)
        {
        }
        // More catches here
```

Some people suggest that you should additionally always catch `\Exception` so that you'll never have uncaught errors. In JavaScript this is not required because exceptions are strings, not objects.

Comment: Sweet, didn't know you could catch multiple different types of exceptions in 1 try.

Comment: Some flavours of JavaScript (Firefox) do have an equivalent to this with conditional catch clauses (`catch (e if e instanceof TypeError) {...} catch (e if e instanceof RangeError) {...}`... which is actually more convoluted than PHP..... and which isn't part of the ECMAScript specification either

Comment: Interesting @Mark, but you're right that syntax is convoluted. Ouch!

Comment: "is actually more convoluted than PHP"
@MarkBaker That's uncalled for and simply untrue, there is no reason to belittle Javascript like that. If you look at my first post here, I don't have to use `$e->getMessage()` to get the thrown error in Javascript, but infact, just have to use `e` in JS. I'm pretty sure that makes up for those frivolous `throw new Exception` lines each time instead of the simple `throw`.  I find it sad you turn this into some 'PHP VS JS' show when I was just looking for shorter ways to use an exception and using what I found ins JS as merely an example.

Comment: I wasn't belittling JavaScript.... I was pointing out that there is a equivalent to PHP's multiple catch blocks.... I was not turning anything into a PHP vs JavaScript debate, although the use of an `if` in the "catch block" surely qualifies as `convoluted` and less intuitive to write

Comment: @Nick, you have quite clearly misunderstood Mark, and your sharp tone is unwarranted. Language wars tend to be discouraged on Stack Overflow, but comparisons between languages are - surely? - perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Saying 'actually more convoluted than PHP' is not me having a language war or me having a sharp tone. His statement is unwarranted, not mine. There is no reason to put Javascript down because you're a PHP fanatic, show respect for both languages.

Comment: " although the use of an if in the "catch block" surely qualifies as convoluted and less intuitive to write".  No it doesn't, not when comparing it to this issue. Want to know what is more convoluted having to right `throw new Exception` each time you want to error out, instead of just `throw`. Specifically, when in your example, you're using that catch block only one time instead of multiple throws... and you still have the audacity to say that. That's why I said it was uncalled for.

Comment: I think you're reading Mark's comments through the mindset of language competition, but having read his material here for years, he certainly is not like that. Hopefully @Nick you can just cheerfully agree to disagree. Let's keep our civility hats on `:-)`.

Comment: OK! It was uncalled for and I apologise that I said anything that might have been interpreted as "dissing" javascript..... clearly an `if` test inside a "catch block" isn't convoluted, but perfectly acceptable within the framework of javascript